# How to display comments inline

Tags: php, jquery, css, comments

So I have this code (which works) that prints out the comments a user has just written. The issue im having is with displaying the comments. The username is displayed above the comment and I just want them to be displayed next to each other for example

'Username:'comment''

I have tried putting display:inline; in my CSS for h4 and p but it messes up everything else that i have put into these elements.

Does anyone know the answer?

This is my code

```
 //Print out existing comment
    $query = "SELECT * FROM comments JOIN users ON comments.userID = users.ID WHERE salonID=$salonid"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
    if (!$result) die("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error($db_server));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $str_comments .= "<div id='comments'><h4>" . $row['Username'] ."</h4><p>'" . $row['comment'] . "'</p>";
            $str_comments .="<img src='" . $row['imagename'] ."' /></div>";
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `<h4>` for the username?

Comment: <h4> and <p> are blocks elements…

You need to use <span> or other inlines elements.

Or you can use float:left; and clear:left at the end.

Comment: Just to make it stand out a bit more

Comment: To stand out you can use <span class="title">user</span><span>comment</span>

and use css for .title

Comment: I put it into a class

 $str_comments .= "<span class='comments'><h4>" . $row['Username'] ."</h4>'" . $row['comment'] . "'</span>";

and in my css styled this as display:inline; 

but it still doesnt display inline, sorry Im very new to PHP/HTML/CSS

Comment: ah I fixed it! I removed the h4 tag and it works, thanks guys!

Comment: drop h4 it's block element so the h4 width is 100%

Answer (score 0):

You put username inside `<h4></h4>` which is a block element. It's the same for `<p></p>`.

Block element will take a full row so you won't be able to place username & comment in a line.

You already give `display:inline` style for `<h4></h4>` & `<p></p>` it should be fine.

I encourage you to use a `<span></span>` instead which is an inline element by default.

Focus on this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  $str_comments .= "<div id='comments'>" . 
                   "<span style='font-weigth:bold;'>" . $row['Username'] ."</span>" .
                   "<span>'" . $row['comment'] . "'</span>" . 
                   "<img src='" . $row['imagename'] ."' />".
                   "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it on your website is use annote ( http://annote.in ). A javascript based inline comment plugin. You can get started on any platform in minutes.